# Updating multiple columns with one subquery

Tags: sqlite, sql-update, aggregate

I have a classical parent - child relationship in sqlite:

```
create table tq84_parent (
  id                int primary key,
  avg_val           float,
  min_val           float,
  max_val           float
);

create table tq84_child (
  id_parent         int references tq84_parent,
  val               int
);
```

which is filled as follows

```
insert into tq84_parent (id) values(1);
insert into tq84_parent (id) values(2);

insert into tq84_child values (1,  1);
insert into tq84_child values (1,  2);
insert into tq84_child values (1,  3);

insert into tq84_child values (2,  6);
insert into tq84_child values (2,  7);
insert into tq84_child values (2,  8);
insert into tq84_child values (2,  9);
insert into tq84_child values (2, 10);
```

Now, I'd like to update `tq84_parent` that its columns `avg_val`, `min_val` and `max_val` reflect the according aggregate values of its child table.

I can achieve this with this statement:

```
update 
  tq84_parent
set
  avg_val = (select avg(val) from tq84_child where id_parent = id),
  min_val = (select min(val) from tq84_child where id_parent = id),
  max_val = (select max(val) from tq84_child where id_parent = id);
```

The result, as desired is:

```
.mode columns

select * from tq84_parent;

1           2.0         1.0         3.0
2           8.0         6.0         10.0
```

I fear, however, that the performance of such a statement is not optimal as the number of records grows in both `tq84_parent` and `tq84_child` because almost the same query is made three times instead of once.

So, I'd like to go with something like

```
update
  tq84_parent
set
 (
  avg_val,
  min_val,
  max_val
 )
= (select
     avg(val),
     min(val),
     max(val)
   from
     tq84_child
   where
     id_parent = id
);
```

which doesn't work.

So, is there a way to rewrite my query?

Comment: Is this your actual `tq84_parent` table, or are there more columns?

Comment: There are more columns in `tq84_parent`. If it makes a difference, I'd still be interested for a solution where it were the actual `tq84_parent` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `id` and `id_parent` are primary and foreign keys it means `id` is unique and `id_parent` always references an existing id.

That means you can use [`REPLACE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_replace.html) to change the table since the unique key is always violated (aka no inserts will be done), and `REPLACE` can take a subquery and set multiple columns at once;

```
REPLACE INTO tq84_parent (id, avg_val, min_val, max_val)
  SELECT id_parent, AVG(val), MIN(val), MAX(val)
  FROM tq84_child
  GROUP BY id_parent;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ac1d9/1).

Note: As CL points out, fields that are not set in the query will have their default values since the rows are *replaced*, not *updated*. This means that if you have other fields in the table that you need to keep unchanged, your old method is still the way to do it.

Comment: REPLACE never updates the table, it just deletes the old row.

Comment: @CL. You are correct of course, that's what I get for answering database questions before first coffee. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The actual speed of the query execution depends mostly of the amount of disk I/O that needs to be done.

With the database schema shown above, each subquery needs to scan the entire table.
If you have a covering index on all the columns needed to compute the aggregate values, each subquery needs to scan only a small part of the index, so in practice, the data is guaranteed to already be in the cache when doing multiple subqueries for the same ID:

```
CREATE INDEX xxx ON tq84_child(id_parent, val);
```